# How to define project dependency without copying or consuming output

Tags: c#, .net-core, msbuild

I want to use a `<ProjectReference>` to ensure a dependency project builds first. I don't want to reference the project's output assembly or copy any files or transient dependencies of the dependency project.

My specific use case is that I have a test project which uses [`Testcontainers`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Testcontainers) to run the dependency project via Docker and I want to ensure the container is always rebuilt when any files change. If I only define a solution-level build order dependency, it doesn't rebuild the containerized project when changes are made.

Effectively, the dependency is a "compile-time only" dependency.

I tried to define a dependency using `<ProjectReferece>` but could not achieve both:

1. avoiding a runtime-reference to the dependency project
2. avoiding copying any of the files of the dependency into the dependent project's output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `<ProjectReference>` but you'll need to set three properties to false:

- Private: Copy the referenced project assembly dll to the referencing project output directory.
- ReferenceOutputAssembly: Link to the referenced assembly. This manages your ability to use the assembly in your code.
- CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies: Copy other assemblies depended upon by the referenced project.

```xml
<ProjectReference Include="Dependency.csproj">
  <Private>False</Private>
  <CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>False</CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies>
  <ReferenceOutputAssembly>false</ReferenceOutputAssembly>
</ProjectReference>
```

Comment: The `CopyLocalSatelliteAssemblies` attribute was the secret sauce I needed. Thanks!